# An if statement with multiple conditions

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax

Due to my lack of knowledge in Bash, I come to you with a trivial problem.  I have an 'Apps' directory of 41 folders.  In each folder, there is a `css` subdirectory containing a glue1.css file.  My goal is to remove that css file via a bash loop, but I need to exempt two folders: `ad` and `glue-resources`.

I need to exempt the `ad` folder because there is no css file.  I want to prevent the following error from occurring upon execution:

```
rm: ad/css/glue1.css: No such file or directory
```

Consider this hypothetical directory (lacking 41 folders for brevity):

```
Apps
  ad
    css
      (empty)
  glue-resources
    css
      glue1.css (keep this file!)
  profile
    css
      glue1.css (remove this file!)
  ...
```

Here is the code I have so far.  It should call `rm` on the glue1.css file if the parent directory path is NOT equal to `glue-resources/css/` or `ad/css/`.

```
for dir in **/css/; do
if [[ "${dir}" != 'glue-resources/css/' || "${dir}" != 'ad/css/' ]]; then
    rm "${dir}"glue1.css
fi
done
```

The above code results doesn't work.  I get the same 'No such file or directory' error and the glue1.css file in `glue-resources/css` has been removed.   I'm not quite sure why it doesn't work—I read somewhere that if you use `[[` and `]]` you can combine multiple conditions.

I think the problem is that I don't understand how multiple conditions in bash work.  The following versions of the code work.

```
for dir in **/css/; do
if [[ "${dir}" != 'glue-resources/css/' ]]; then
    rm "${dir}"glue1.css
fi
done


for dir in **/css/; do
if [[ "${dir}" != 'ad/css/' ]]; then
    rm "${dir}"glue1.css
fi
done
```

My attempt to add multiple conditions to the if statement failed.

Comment: Try out [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net), it would have autodetected [this issue](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2055).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `||` represents logical-OR, the following condition will always return true:

```
[[ "${dir}" != 'glue-resources/css/' || "${dir}" != 'ad/css/' ]]
```

I suspect that what you want is:

```
[[ "${dir}" != 'glue-resources/css/' && "${dir}" != 'ad/css/' ]]
```

`&&` is logical-AND.  It requires that both conditions be met at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could avoid the loop and do something like this:

```
find . -path ./glue-resources -prune -o -name glue1.css | xargs -I [] rm []
```