# An if statement with AND operator

Tags: bash, if-statement, and-operator

Trying to comparisons with a variable against strings, i tried code as per the solution from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67898/using-the-not-equal-operator-for-string-comparison

```
if [ "$ACTION" != "dry" ] && [ "$ACTION" != "prune" ]
then
    echo "Invalid"
fi
```

This does not work for me, i get no error messages it's like it just skips the code block.

I have also tried like this as per answer here [Bash if statement with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819022/bash-if-statement-with-multiple-conditions)

```
if [[ "$ACTION" != "dry" && "$ACTION" != "prune" ]]
then
    echo "Invalid"
fi
```

This echoes "Invalid" if $ACTION is anything other than "dry", even if its "prune"

Any suggestions?

---

**EDIT**

Full code

```
OPTIND=1
while getopts "b:a:" option
do
    case "${option}"
    in
        b) MERGE_BRANCH=${OPTARG};;
        a) ACTION=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done

if [[ "$ACTION" != "dry" && "$ACTION" != "prune" ]]
then
    echo "Invalid"
fi

shift $((OPTIND-1))
[ "$1" = "--" ] && shift

(( 1 <= ${#} )) || { echo "missing mandatory argument" 2>&1 ; exit 1;     };
```

Comment: How does `ACTION` get set? What is the output of `declare -p ACTION`? I suspect the value has trailing whitespace (specifically, a carriage return).

Comment: @chepner declaring action outputs correctly `declare -- ACTION="prune"`                                                                                         It is set with getopts like this                                                                 `while getopts "b:a:" option
do
    case "${option}"
    in
        b) MERGE_BRANCH=${OPTARG};;
        a) ACTION=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done`

Comment: This echoes "Invalid" if $ACTION is anything other than "dry", even if its "prune" → not for me: it does not print "Invalid" if `ACTION` equals `prune`.

Comment: @A.Jac Post the *exact* code you run to get the output you claim, instead of assuming that the valid code you do post will produce the same problem.

Comment: Edited OP with full code

Comment: `tmp.sh -a prune` does not print `Invalid` with the code you posted above.

Answer (score 3):

Well, in most situations where such a command arises, using `case` provides a more maintainable solution, because during the life cycle of your script you will want to change action names, deal with new situations, and so on:

```
case "$ACTION" in 
  ("dry"|"prune") 
    : # Insert appropriate code
  ;;
  (*)
    echo Invalid
  ;;
esac
```

Second, there is no need to use the `[[` syntax in this case

```
if [ "$ACTION" != dry ] && [ "$ACTION" != prune ]; then
  echo Invalid
fi
```

is enough in this case. To test that everything is working as expected, you can add an `else` branch:

```
if [ "$ACTION" != dry ] && [ "$ACTION" != prune ]; then
  echo Invalid
else
  echo Valid
fi
```

Comment: `-a` is obsolete and should not be used in new code. Use `[ ... ] && [ ... ]` instead.

Comment: `!=` does not perform a regular expression match; it performs a pattern match *if* the RHS contains an unquoted pattern.

Comment: I got it to work using `case` and moving the check after the `shift` operation. This seems to work as intended, updating OP with solution

Comment: @chepner Thank you for your comments. I corrected my answer accordingly.

Comment: @A.Jac That's actually not a good practice. The question should be just that, a question - and not a question _and_ an answer. If what you've added is just this answer, you can just remove it; if you've found a different solution, you should add it as a proper answer.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Okay, since i cant delete i will add my solution as an answer

Comment: @A.Jac You can't edit the question? Never mind, looks like you just did.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I thought you meant remove the entire question.

Comment: @A.Jac Oh, no, I just meant not adding an answer to the question body.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Using case as per @Dario's answer and moving the check to after the shift operation makes the code work as intended.

```
OPTIND=1

while getopts "b:a:" option
do
    case "${option}"
    in
        b) MERGE_BRANCH=${OPTARG};;
        a) ACTION=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))
[ "$1" = "--" ] && shift

(( 1 <= ${#} )) || { echo "missing mandatory argument" 2>&1 ; exit 1; };

case "$ACTION" in
  (dry|prune)
    :
  ;;
  (*)
    echo "Invalid argument"
    exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

Comment: I'm glad your code is working now, but I really don't see how this had any significant effect.